# How to work with predictor variables which are all categorical but the target variable is an integer?

Tags: predictive-modeling

I have historical data with time (hour, day, etc.) and region code linked to number of events in the integer format. I was starting to build a model in R to predict number of events given time and region. I explored SVM in R but seems like it is a non-starter with categorical variables. Any other approach which might of use here. Thanks for your response.

Comment: could dummy factors help out? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52915/how-to-deal-with-an-svm-with-categorical-attributes

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a [dummy variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)) from your categorical variables. Almost all machine learning algorithms can't work with categorical variables.

Comment: Some algorithms that _can_ work with categoricals, are decision tree (by extension, random forest), naive bayes (only for classification), knn.